# How do I make `window.scrollTo` more precise?

Tags: javascript

When I click on `box1`, the scroll effect needs to scroll down to `box2` (top edge of the blue box). This works fine on web, but I'm not able to replicate the effect at a precise point on mobile.

```js
document.getElementById('box1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 507,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.gap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box1" id="box1"></div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
  <div class="box2" id="box2"></div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
  <div class="box3" id="box3"></div>
</body>
```

When clicking on `box1` in an IPhone simulator, `scrollTo` takes me to the bottom half of the yellow box.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're scrolling to a specific coordinate (`top: 507`), which is going to be different on mobile.

Use JavaScript to fetch the `top` of coordinate of the specific element you want to scroll to:

```
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
document.getElementById('box1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: box2.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
});
```

Comment: you said: `which is going to be different on mobile`. how do I make it mobile friendly? Any suggestion?

Comment: Well one thing is, if you need to scroll to an element, scroll to that exact element rather than to your guess/estimate of where it is. And that's the case even if you were only developing for web. If you're wondering about strategies for making web apps work nicely on mobile, that's a different and broader question